# linq query to join two tables and get the count from one table values from the other

Tags: .net, sql, linq, .net-3.5, lambda

I have two tables Customers, Orders

**Customers**
CustomerID
FName
LName

**Orders**
OrderId
CustomerID
OrderDate

I want to make a linq statement that can join these two tables and get 
FName, LName, Count of orders for each customer

Answer (score 6):

```
from c in Customers
join o in Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into g
select new { c.FName, c.LName, Count=g.Count() }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from c in db.Customers
let theCount = c.Orders.Count()
select new {c.FName, c.LName, theCount}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic11

> These access operations translate to more complicated joins or correlated sub-queries **in the equivalent SQL**, allowing you to walk through your object graph during a query.

Comment: This assumes a linq-to-objects type of relationship where a Customer object contains a List of Orders

Comment: LinqToSql can model this relationship.  This evaluations is done 100% in the database.

Comment: Does this assume the relationships are set up correctly in the database with Orders having an FK to Customers? Otherwise how would it know what c.Orders is?

Comment: Doesn't matter if the FK is set in the database, just add the relationship in the LinqToSql designer.